# Parsing a byte file in pascal

Tags: windows, parsing, pascal, lazarus

All i need to do is parse a single bye file to read the contents to the screen but i dont know how to parse could someone please give me some rough coding i could enter file addresses in or any idea on how to parse?

this is where i currently am at

```
program Reordering;

uses crt;

  var f, i: text;
  s: string;
  skyf: array [1..256] of byte;
  j: integer;
  result: array [1..256] of char;

begin
  assign(f, 'C:\Users\Peter John Arnold\Documents\Coding\EDID1.LOG_JVC_TV_Model_LT19DK8ZJ.file');
  j := 1;
  Assign(i, 'C:\Users\Peter John Arnold\Documents\Coding\TV File\TvFile.txt');
  rewrite(f);
  reset(f);
  rewrite(i);

  repeat
    readln(f, skyf[j]);
    Result[j] := char(skyf[j]);
    Append(i);
    write(i, (skyf[j]));
    j := j + 1;
  until EOF(f);
  close(f);
  close(i);
  s := result[1..256];
  write(s);
  readln();
end.
```

Comment: Can you give some information on the file content you're trying to parse and what you've tried so far that isn't working for you? You're asking you to help you parse the file with no info about the file; it's like asking us to translate a voice you're hearing from whatever language it's speaking into English, but not letting us hear the voice or know the language. Please show some file content, what you're expecting to get from it, and the code you've written so far that you need help with, and I'm sure someone here can help you. :-)

Comment: What compiler are you using and for what operating system?

Comment: ok im very sorry well im using lazarus as my enviroment and its for windows. I have been looking for a while to find some way to do it with out any luck. i have a 256 byte file and each byte needs to be transfered from a char. i can read from the file just fien but all of it is in ascii for some reason i will copy some of my code into another comment!

Comment: program Reordering;
uses crt;

var f,i:text;
    s:string;
    skyf:array [1..256] of byte;
    j:integer;

begin
  assign(f,'C:\Users\Peter John Arnold\Documents\Coding\EDID1.LOG_JVC_TV_Model_LT19DK8ZJ.file');
   j:=1;
  Assign(i,'C:\Users\Peter John Arnold\Documents\Coding\TV File\TvFile.txt');
  reset(f);
  rewrite(i);
  repeat
    readln(f,skyf[j]);
    j:=j+1;
  until EOF(f);
  close(f);
  close(i);




end.

Comment: Please don't add code and additional information to comments. You can edit your own question to provide the information there, where people can easily see it when they read your question. (You can also properly format code so it's actually readable.) :-) Also, your code makes no sense; you're opening and truncating `i`, but never do anything with it (you read from `j`, but do nothing with what you read) except close it again.

Comment: ahh ok i am very sorry !! well i think im almost there on my own ! ive gotten to the stage where i can get a 0 from the file but im not usre if some of my functions are working! ill update my code in the question for you to look at

Comment: **Please** take the time to properly format your code so we can read it. You can do that when you paste it in - just indent each line at least four spaces (more if needed for proper indentation). You can even preview it almost WYSIWYG in the area right below where you're entering it. The easier you make your question to read, the better your chances of getting an answer. (And it's annoying to people when they take the time to fix your formatting and then you replace the content again with more unformatted code.)

Comment: omg im so sorry i keep doing this!!! thank you so much ken!! i was just updating the code because ive added more to it!

Answer (score 0):

**For parsing the binary file:**

1. Read byte array from file ([How to read and change a binary file](http://community.freepascal.org/bboards/message?message_id=266412&forum_id=24084))
2. Convert byte array obtained from file to string (every byte to
   corresponding ASCII char - "chr"-function)
3. Use existing parsing libraries (e.g. "regexpr" unit)

**Note**: use "AnsiString" type